# textfields values issue iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Using the below code, but I am not getting the value of result in textfields ... any help

```
-(IBAction) scanButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    int button = [sender tag];

    if (button == 1) {
        NSLog(@"ID Button Pressed");
        deviceID.text = result;
    }
    else if (button == 2){
        NSLog(@"Key button Pressed");
        deviceKey.text = result;
    }

    NSLog(@"TBD: scan barcode here...");

    // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];

    // present and release the controller
    [self presentModalViewController: reader animated: YES];

    [reader release];
}

-(void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    // ADD: get the decode results

    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data


    result = symbol.data;

    NSLog(@"result = %@",result);

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
    resultImage.image =
    [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)
    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];    
}
```

Comment: Are you just talking about `deviceID` and `deviceKey` text fields in the first function?

Comment: yes i am talking about deviceID and deviceKey textfields

Comment: Do you have proper outlets connected? Is `NSLog` prints the correct value?

Comment: i am getting the value properly in result = symbol.data; but how can i assign this value to the relative textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of following line

```
result = symbol.data;
```

Use the following

```
if( result )
  [result release];

result = [symbol.data retain];
```

Comment: getting the value in result but not being shown in deviceID textfield, but in deviceKey its showing the value

Comment: Seems like an outlet connection issue if it will show in one but not the other.

Comment: checked that, its connected properly,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `result` is correct and is equal to `symbol.data`, you should be able to set the text using:

```
[deviceID setText: result];
```

or

```
[deviceKey setText: result];
```

considering `symbol.data` is an NSString object. If that isn't working, your outlets are not connected properly (the deviceID and/or deviceKey outlets) in Interface Builder.